# how to write stored procedure in Oracle 11g

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have tried simple stored procedure in oracle 11g through sql developer as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P1 AS 
BEGIN
DBMS.OUTPUT.PUT.LINE('WELCOME TO ORACLE');
END P1;
```

but still I am getting following error:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

I am not getting exactly how to solve this error. Can anyone please help me..?

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. You already have a procedure with name P1 and its telling that it cannot create another procedure with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all. You already have a stored procedure named as P1, so either drop the existing one or give this procedure a different name. To check if the procedure already exists use this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_PROCEDURES
 WHERE object_name = 'P1'
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_OBJECTS
 WHERE object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
   AND object_name = 'P1'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

First of all, you've probably already save the stored procedure once. So you cannot *create* it anymore but have to *replace* it. Second, the procedure name for writing output is misspelled.

So try this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P1 AS 
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WELCOME TO ORACLE');
END P1;
/
```

Comment: OK..Thanks a lot  friend.. actually I used to work with sql server so there is difference in syntax of oracle and sql server so maybe i got confused..
but Thanks for your help..:)